# How to remove '\n' from scrapy output in python

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to output to CSV but I realized that when scraping tripadvisor I am getting many carriage returns thus the array goes over 30 while there are only 10 reviews so I get many fields missing. Is there a way to remove the carriage returns.

spider.

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapingtest.items import ScrapingTestingItem
from collections import OrderedDict
import json
from scrapy.selector.lxmlsel import HtmlXPathSelector
import csv
import html2text
import unicodedata


class scrapingtestspider(Spider):
    name = "scrapytesting"
    allowed_domains = ["tripadvisor.in"]
    base_uri = ["tripadvisor.in"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g297679-d736080-Reviews-Ooty_Elk_Hill_A_Sterling_Holidays_Resort-Ooty_Tamil_Nadu.html"]



    def parse(self, response):
        item = ScrapingTestingItem()
        sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        converter = html2text.HTML2Text()
        sites = sel.xpath('//a[contains(text(), "Next")]/@href').extract()
##        dummy_test = [ "" for k in range(10)]

        item['reviews'] = sel.xpath('//div[@class="col2of2"]//p[@class="partial_entry"]/text()').extract()
        item['subjects'] = sel.xpath('//span[@class="noQuotes"]/text()').extract()
        item['stars'] = sel.xpath('//*[@class="rating reviewItemInline"]//img/@alt').extract()
        item['names'] = sel.xpath('//*[@class="username mo"]/span/text()').extract()
        item['location'] = sel.xpath('//*[@class="location"]/text()').extract()
        item['date'] = sel.xpath('//*[@class="ratingDate relativeDate"]/@title').extract()
        item['date'] += sel.xpath('//div[@class="col2of2"]//span[@class="ratingDate"]/text()').extract()


        startingrange = len(sel.xpath('//*[@class="ratingDate relativeDate"]/@title').extract())

        for j in range(startingrange,len(item['date'])):
            item['date'][j] = item['date'][j][9:].strip()

        for i in range(len(item['stars'])):
            item['stars'][i] = item['stars'][i][:1].strip()

        for o in range(len(item['reviews'])):
            print unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', unicode(item['reviews'][o])).encode('ascii', 'ignore')

        for y in range(len(item['subjects'])):
            item['subjects'][y] = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', unicode(item['subjects'][y])).encode('ascii', 'ignore')

        yield item

#        print item['reviews']

        if(sites and len(sites) > 0):
            for site in sites:
                yield Request(url="http://tripadvisor.in" + site, callback=self.parse)
```

Is there possible a regex that I could use to go through the for loop and replace it. I tried replace but that did not do a thing. And also why does scrapy do that.

Comment: you can use `.replace("\n", "")`

Comment: see but that is not going to work because then in the array it is going to be 30 containing "". I need to remove it form the array. Like something where It finds it and then removes the index. Im used to java so I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: TL/DR it works but the array index still exists thus outputting blank space

Comment: I see, so you want to remove them from the array and only keep the 10 reviews? Can you post your array?

Comment: Figured it out, after reading about lists on python.org I saw I could use `while "\n" in list: list.remove("\n")`

Comment: thanks for your support!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I usually do to trim and clean up the output is using [Input and/or Output Processors](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#input-and-output-processors) with [Item Loaders](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) - it makes things more modular and clean:

```
class ScrapingTestingLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()
```

Then, if you would use this Item Loader for loading your items, you'll get the extracted values stripped and as strings (instead of lists). For instance, if the extracted field is `["my value \n"]` - you'll get `my value` as an output.

Comment: I assume this would go outside the spider folder where Items reside. I'm brand new to scrapy I would need to experiment with this. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @Smashed thanks for the update. I usually have a separate `loaders.py` near `items.py`, but you can put your loaders in `items.py` also (in case the `Item` and `ItemLoader` classes are short and transparent).

Comment: @Smashed you should definitely study that - this would actually help you better organize your web-scraping code and make your project more modular and clean.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution after reading the list docs.

```
while "\n" in some_list: some_list.remove("\n")
```

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer so others don't bother, that is not an uncommon thing to do.

Comment: Yeah, that could be so. Try to not forget to. :)